# Spring Security SAML standalone webapplication

Tags: tomcat, spring-security, saml

I've deployed the spring-security-saml2-sample web application and configured it to use our IdP. All is working well, except that I want to use it as a standalone webapp. More concretely, I want all requests to be intercepted by the Spring Security webapp, based on the URLs defined in the securityContext.xml.

In order to do this I've mapped the SAML app to the ROOT path in Tomcat. This way, all URLs accessed on this server are mapped to this application. However, the webapp I'm trying to secure has another path (let's say "/app"), and is not intercepted by the SAML app responsible for securing everything.

Is there a way to map all URLs to this security application? (similar to a Tomcat Valve I think)